# REACT filtering objects in array based on values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, filter

i have an array of objects **employees** that looks something like this :

```
 [
{ nameAR:"عاصم ماجد شوشاري",nameEN:"aasem majed shoshari",age:"23",maritalStatus:"single" },
{ nameAR:"عاصم ماجد شوشاري",nameEN:"aasem majed shoshari",age:"23",maritalStatus:"single" },
{ nameAR:"عاصم ماجد شوشاري",nameEN:"aasem majed shoshari",age:"23",maritalStatus:"single" },
{ nameAR:"عاصم ماجد شوشاري",nameEN:"aasem majed shoshari",age:"23",maritalStatus:"single" },
{ nameAR:"عاصم ماجد شوشاري",nameEN:"aasem majed shoshari",age:"23",maritalStatus:"single" },

]
```

assuming that those objects are not the same and are different data, i want to filter this array **onChange** based on matching object values to the search field value:

```
  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    const filteredArray = employees.filter((emp) => 
      Object.values(emp).map((value) => {
        return value.includes(e.target.value);
      })
);
    console.log(filteredArray);
  };

  ...
        <input
          type="search"
          placeholder="Search employees.."
          className="searchInput"
          onChange={handleSearch}
        />
  ...
```

but **filteredArray** returns an empty array, i want it to return the objects that any of its values characters matches search input value characters, how to do that?

Comment: You forgot to return anything from `map`. You have to either use `return` or remove `[}`

Comment: now it returns the array as it is

Comment: If you have 4 the same items in the array, it will find the search phrase in every element.

Comment: yeah "if", but those are just repeated values, i have different data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the `handleSearch` function should be in your case:

```js
const handleSearch = (e) => {
  const searchKey = e.target.value;
  return employees.filter((employee) =>
    Object.values(employee).join(' ').includes(searchKey)
  );
};
```

`Object.values(employee)` will result in:

```
['عاصم ماجد شوشاري', 'aasem majed shoshari', '23', 'single']
```

`Object.values(employee).join(' ')` will result in:

```
'عاصم ماجد شوشاري aasem majed shoshari 23 single'
```

`Object.values(employee).join(" ").includes(searchKey)` to check if that string has your `searchKey`.

Note that your `employees` array's objects have the same key-values pairs, so even if you run this code that is correct you will either see the full list of employees or none.

Comment: This probably doesn't make any difference here

Comment: he uses  ``` join```  on the resulted array and i used ```map```, this actually works and mine doesn't, i don't why